# android text view give runtime error in eclipse

Tags: android

In the code below I get runtime error in eclipse. Why this error is not displayed at compile time?

```
public class AndroidUIActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;
    private int maxtime=0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    int fileSize=0;
    private MediaPlayer mp3player;
    private TextView txt_Currenttime;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txt_Currenttime.setText(12); /* line with error */
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide formatted question, yours horrible

Comment: Also, A dump of the error can help.

Comment: Did you initialize txt_Currenttime?

Answer (score 2):

First identify the Textview id

```
Text view txt_Currenttime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
```

then set the value

```
txt_Currenttime.setText(String.valueOf(12));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like:

```
txt_Currenttime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
txt_Currenttime.setText(String.valueOf(12));
```

before setting the text.

Comment: txt_Currenttime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
txt_Currenttime.setText(String.valueOf(12));

Answer (score 0):

The Run time error is coming because you are setting integer value as a text of textview but textview is not take integer value, Change below line of your code

`txt_Currenttime.setText(12);`

to

`txt_Currenttime.setText(String.valueOf(12));` or `txt_Currenttime.setText("12");`

And add below line after `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

```
txt_Currenttime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTxtView1);
```

it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt_Currenttime.setText(12);
```

In this line ? 
The textView needs to be set using a String

```
txt_Currenttime.setText("12");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to first find the id of that textview after that you can apply any operation on that textview. you are not initializing the textview but you are using it so first use the below code then set text. and you have to set the text in double quotes.

```
txt_Currenttime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
txt_Currenttime.setText("12");
```

Answer (score 0):

In java `private TextView txt_Currenttime` means that you just have a reference, so you need to build an object (with a `new`) before using `txt_Currenttime`.